# Include Shopify & Stripe within an ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, shopify, kentico, stripe-payments

Are there any clear, step by step tutorials explaining how to include my shopify store that is already using Stripe into an MVC application for an ecommerce site using Kentico CMS?

Is it as simple as using JSON to call the Shopify API?  I know you need to use liquid within the views, but can this be combined with Razor?  I be using Kentico CMS which I hear is now workable with MVC, but very buggy (maybe this is fixed int he newer version??). Also - I am a huge fan of Twitter bootstrap's scaffolding and plugins as well as .less files.  I've used it within mvc applications, and I'm assuming it would work within kentico and/or liquid , but was just wondering if anybody had tried using twitter bootstrap within a liquid page or integrated with Kentico.  I'm assuming it would play nicely with kentico since it's just css and scripts.

Basically, my issues are

- Is Kentico CMS a suitable CMS to use with .NET MVC?  If not, what about N2, or other CMS for .net?
- Can liquid code be used alongside razor code?
- How difficult is it to use or integrate a shopify page in a .net mvc view?
- Has anybody had experience using Twitter Bootstrap within a liquid page or within Kentico?

I can find bits and pieces of this information, but I was just hoping that somebody out there had documented this already.  Any links or tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer with regards to using some of the Kentico questions.

Kentico plays well with bootstrap and less, however make sure you turn off allow css minification in the settings or else you will receive errors. I personally have used both dotless and less.js with kentico fine with bootstrap.

Site Manager > Settings > System > Performance > Resources.

Also I have never found Kentico that great to work with in MVC. It is even the the least  recommended template engine that Kentico themselves recommend. Orchard CMS on the other hand is great for working with MVC but it is rather young and lacks a lot of features.